# How to move Joomla from old hoster to bluehost

Tags: mysql, joomla

Have a client asking for me to move their Joomla site from register.com to bluehost.com.  Is everything in the DB?  I was imaging deploying a fresh Joomla at bluehost.com via SimpleScripts and importing a DB backup from register.com.  Is this feasible?  I'd like to overwrite Joomla app files on bluehost.com so that SimpleScripts can manage upgrades in the future.  Is this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The majority of the content is stored in the database, but this excludes uploaded content: attachments, images, themes and stylesheets and the configuration.php all of which live in the Joomla directory.

There is also a guide in the official documentation on how to do this: http://docs.joomla.org/Copying_a_Joomla_website

Answer (score 0):

Do a MySQL dump of the database that Joomla uses. You can find out the name of this database by looking in the root directory for the Joomla installation for a file configuration.php. Look in there for the DB name. After you do the MySQL dump, place that .sql file in the root Joomla directory. Then create a compressed tar file.

Then give the compressed tar file to Bluehost to do the migration for you.

To do backups of the Joomla website in the future, write a shell script and put it in the CRON to do the MySQL dump and compressed tar file. Then do an rsync for off-site backup.